# Multiplication of lim sups

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be bounded sequences of nonegative numbers. Prove $\text{lim sup} (s_nt_n) \leq (\text{lim sup} s_n)(\text{lim sup}$ t_n).

EDIT: new approach.
Since $s_n \geq 0$ and $t_n \geq0$ then $0\leq\{s_k:k\geq n\}$ and $0\leq\{t_k:k\geq n\}$.

Now suppose $\epsilon >0$ and for $n\in \mathbb N$ and $k \geq n$ that
$s_kt_k \leq (s_k) \text{sup} \{t_k:k\geq n\} \leq \text {sup} \{s_k:k\geq n\}\text{sup}\{t_k:k\geq n\}$ where I used that multiplication of nonegative numbers is preserved (and I followed from a different proof and am honestly sort of lost on this).

Thus $\text{sup}\{s_kt_k:k\geq n\} \leq \text{sup}\{s_k:k\geq n\}\text{sup}\{t_k:k\geq n\}$ which would follow for limits so $\text{lim sup} (s_nt_n) \leq (\text{lim sup}s_n)(\text{lim sup} t_n)$.

Comment: What can you say about $\sup(s_nt_n)$ in comparison to $\sup(s_n)\sup(t_n)$?

Comment: I would assume that $\text{sup}(s_nt_n) \leq \text{sup}s_n\text{sup}t_n$?

Comment: Comments after the edit: first, nonnegative means $\geq 0$, not $> 0$. Next, what does $0 < \{s_k : k \geq n\}$ mean? The LHS is a number, and the RHS is a set. For the step $s_k t_k \leq (s_k) \sup\{t_k : k \geq n\}$, you need not only nonnegativeness of $s_k$ but also boundedness of $t_k$. (Otherwise the RHS might be of the form $0 \cdot \infty$, which is undefined.) Make sure you understand this step fully before proceeding to the limsup step, which also requires a careful argument which you haven't made.

Comment: I believe setting up $0\leq\{s_k:k\geq n\}$ means the sequence is nonnegative or its positive(?). I understand your comment on how $s_k$ must be bounded, I often read that $\{s_k:k\geq n\}$ is the "definition" for $s_n$.